# Trying to figure out the name of this car part!

Tags: engine, tires, suspension, part-identification, un105

I got new tires today and saw that the part that's circled is broken on my car. It looks like it just snapped at the top because part of the bolt appears to still be in whatever the tube is. Anyone know the name of the thing circled in red?

If it helps, I have a 2000 Ford Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a Stabilizer Bar Link for your steering stabilizer.

Answer (score 4):

Wakeeta is right: this is your stabilizer bar link (AKA sway bar link).  This is apparently a common failure point.  Here's a [very similar picture](http://www.explorerforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=243367).  A quick shopping search indicates that a replacement part is [on the order of $30](http://www.autopartswarehouse.com/mmp/ford~explorer~sway_bar~parts.html) (sweat equity not included).

Answer (score 0):

It's also called ''sway bar link''